# Discord.py moving a channel to another category if message is sent in a specific category

Tags: python, discord, botframework

So I am basically designing a simple "Help" bot that's similar to a Token bot. Basically, if you need help with anything, from a school subject to a question about a hobby, you can send a message in an "Available Help Channels" category and my bot will move that category to a "Busy Help Channels" category. I got the inspiration from the Python bot in the official Python Discord server, if you're in there and see what I mean. This is my entire code so far:

```
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="ccc ")
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
chanava = [" Help - 1", " Help - 2", " Help - 3", " Help - 4", " Help - 5"]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Casual Cryptic Helper is ready!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ava = get(message.guild.categories, name="Available Help Channels")
    bus = get(message.guild.categories, name="Busy Help Channels")
    if message.content == "ccc setup":
        if ava:
            print("ava")
        else:
            available = await message.guild.create_category("Available Help Channels")
            for channel in chanava:
                await message.guild.create_text_channel(channel, category=available)
        
        if bus:
            print("bus")
        else:
            busy = await message.guild.create_category("Busy Help Channels")
        await message.channel.send("CCH's setup completed for this server! You can begin using the bot.\n\n**Questions, suggestions, or an issue with the bot you found? Contact __Module64#8821__ or __Shadowsprite54#3459__.**")
    else:
        if message.channel not in chanava:
            await message.channel.send("not in help channel")
        else:
            ava = get(message.guild.categories, name="Available Help Channels")
            bus = get(message.guild.categories, name="Busy Help Channels")
            await message.channel.edit(category="Busy Help Channels")
     

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Basically, what it does so far is if the user sends a message "ccc setup", the bot will create two categories in that server: **Available Help Channels** and **Busy Help Channels**. I've figured out how to do that, as well as add help channels to the **Available Help Channels** category. However, my issue is that I'm not able to figure out how to move a channel from the Available Help Channels category to the Busy Help Channels category *when a user sends a message in the Available category.* It's obvious that my bot is detecting when a user sends a message, because it prints "not in help channel", but the problem is that it does this everywhere. I tried a few possible solutions, but none of them seem to work. How could I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: TYPO- where I said **you can send a message in an "Available Help Channels" category and my bot will move that category to a "Busy Help Channels" category**, I meant to say that the bot will move a *channel* to the Busy Help Channels category. Sorry about that mistake.

Comment: You can edit your post if you made a mistake